# How to close window fired up from NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

very nob question: I want to close window programmatically after sent an HTTP POST body data. I read the documentation and I implemented the method 
 - (void) performClose : ( id ) sender;
and
 - ( BOOL ) windowShouldClose : ( id ) sender; But never called. So Please can you put me in right direction from the code provided below to achieve mi target?
   Thank you for your gold time.

my code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

//.h 
@interface PostinoClass : NSWindowController <NSURLSessionDataDelegate,      NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLSessionTaskDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate> {  

NSWindowController *controllerWindow;

}

//.m
- (void)openWindow {    
// NSLog(@"openWindow");
controllerWindow = [[NSWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"SendEmailWindow"];
[controllerWindow showWindow:self];    
}
```

//ok now i can open my cool window, but need to close after some dirty work...

```
- (void)closeWindow:(id)sender {
// NSLog(@"closeWindow");

// [controllerWindow close]; // not work <--
[controllerWindow.window performClose:sender]; //not work too <--
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[self window] close];` That's it.

Documentation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/close).

Comment: Thank you! Your code as is doesn't work, but put me in light.

Comment: @property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *myWindow; link that in IB...
[[self myWindow] close]; //work. 
Views and Windows are not my peculiarity. So Thank you

Comment: If you are in a subclass of NSWindowController the [self window] should work, you are welcomed. You can ping me (by comment) if you have any other questions.

Comment: i will ping you... surely! Thank you mate